# Nginx + Lua - Is it possible to set timeout for an endpoint in Lua code

Tags: nginx, lua

We have the following configuration in the nginx. Inside lua file, we need to set parameters like timeout based on the configuration for the api endpoint. Can we set "ngx.var.proxy_read_timeout" to increase the timeout inside the lua code?

```
{
location ~ ^/(api) {
    // some parameters
    access_by_lua_file "<path_to_lua_file>";
}
```

Regards,
Kumar

Comment: If you find a way, I would love to know. The only solution I have come up with is to basically have another proxy layer with locations which define the timeout, and use those to proxy to the actual location.

Comment: Hi @joshua, Sure.. So you created a separate location block mapping the request and set the timeout? In that you need to replicate all the functionality that you have to this location block..

Comment: Well your functionality can all exist in an include